# Make a ul as input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a ul as input, like in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hailwood/u8zj5/

(but I dont want to use `tagit`, I want to implement it by myself)

I want the user can write something in the input and when he presses the enter key, a li with X button will be inserted to the input.

I really don't know how to implement it.

If I know how to make the ul as input, I will know how to do it.

please help me:

assuming I have the ul:

```
<ul id="countries"></ul>
```

I want to make it writable like in the `jsfiddle` I gave above.

and then it should be something like:

```
$('#countries').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var value; // here I have to get the value of the input
        // insert the li to the ul:
        $('#countries').append('<li value="1">' + value +
                       '&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="closeButton">X</span></li>');
    }
});

$('.closeButton').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: are you looking for `this`?

Comment: `live` is deprecated and gone. Use `$(document).on('click', '.closeButton', ...)`

Comment: @JanDvorak, you forgot to add the link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use contenteditable.

```
<ul id="countries" contenteditable="true"></ul>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
$('#countries').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var value; // here I have to get the value of the input
        // insert the li to the ul:


       var html = $(value).find("ul").append('<li value="1">' + value +
                       '&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="closeButton">X</span></li>');
        $("#countries").val(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you! it doesn't insert the text into the ul..

http://jsfiddle.net/u8zj5/256/

Comment: it is so close, but I want to insert it into the ul and not above.. thank you again!